# Is the file mutex in Linux? How to implement it?

Tags: linux, filesystems

In windows, if I open a file with MS Word, then try to delete it.
The system will stop me. It prevents the file being deleted.

There is a similar mechanism in Linux?
How can I implement it when writing my own program?

Comment: Why would you like to do this, might I ask?

Comment: I'm just curious. I'm using vim and find that I can delete my file in another login shell. Although vim has .swp to recovery it, I want to know why vim and word use different mechanisms.

Comment: I can image only two mechanisms to do that. Read the whole file in memory once(can't edit big file) or in another file(.swp)

Comment: Not being able to read the whole file into memory isn't really a problem for most editors nowadays. Unless you're trying to edit a database file or disk image file or something, it's highly unlikely that you'll have a file too big to fit into virtual memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a similar mechanism in Linux. I, in fact, find that feature of windows to be an incredible misfeature and a big problem.

It is not typical for a program to hold a file open that it is working on anyway unless the program is a database and updating the file as it works. Programs usually just open the file, write contents and close it when you save your document.

`vim`'s `.swp` file is updated as vim works, and vim holds it open the whole time, so even if you delete it, the file doesn't really go away. `vim` will just lose its recovery ability if you delete the `.swp` file while it's running.

In Linux, if you delete a file while a process has it open, the system keeps it in existence until all references to it are gone. The name in the filesystem that refers to the file will be gone. But the file itself is still there on disk.

If the system crashes while the file is still open it will be cleaned up and removed from the disk when the system comes back up.

The reason this is such a problem in Windows is that mandatory locking frequently prevents operations that should succeed from succeeding. For example, a backup process should be able to read a file that is being written to. It shouldn't have to stop the process that is doing the writing before the backup proceeds. In many other cases, operations that should be able to move forward are blocked for silly reasons.

Comment: I despise it. That's why I use Linux, as I can explode my system completely with a file manager ;)

Comment: can you explain why it's a problem? And how do we avoid other user/thread remove my working file? Just check before any file operation?

Comment: @Lai Yu-Hsuan: I've updated my answer. Does my update answer your question?

Comment: "But the file itself is still there on disk." But if I can't reference to its inode, is the file's existence meaningless?

Comment: I misunderstood what you said. You've answered my question. BTW, if opening a file doesn't lock it, why we should always f.close() it? Just a convention?

Comment: @Lai Yu-Hsuan: Because there are a limited number of file descriptors per process. That number is fairly large by default, 1024 on my system. But it's still a limit. If you never `f.close()` it, then the file descriptor will end up hanging around until the process exits, possibly causing a later `open` to fail because of a lack of file descriptors.

Comment: Thank you(and others) so much.

Comment: @LaiYu-Hsuan: Also, closing a file sometimes has the effect of doing a flush, forcing the contents of the file to stable storage. And if you're using a language level (instead of OS level) filehandle the library might be buffering the file in userspace as well. So making sure you close the file gives a greater chance the file will all make it to disk, even if the system is powered off unexpectedly after the close is finished.

Answer (score 3):

The semantics of most Unix filesystems (such as Linux's ext2 fs family) is that a file can be `unlink(2)`'d at any time, even if it is open.  However, after such a call, if the file has been opened by some other process, they can continue to read and write to the file through the open file descriptor.  The filesystem does not actually free the storage until all open file descriptors have been closed.  These are very long-standing semantics.

You may wish to read more about file locking in Unix and Linux (e.g., the [Wikipedia article on File Locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking).)  Basically, mandatory and advisory locks on Linux exist but they're not guaranteed to prevent what you want to prevent.